# RASA: Connection Aborted Error while trying to communicate with the bot

Tags: python-3.x, bots, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have different stories, and just as a starting point, wanted the bot to reply ‘greet’ (Hi, hello etc.)

Reference link: https://github.com/JustinaPetr/Weatherbot_Tutorial/tree/master/Full%20Code%20%5BLatest%20release%20of%20Rasa%20NLU%20and%20Rasa%20Core%5D

I could train the model successfully. (run_model.py). While I run the ‘dialogue_management_model.py’, I hit the following error.

I get the following prompt to type the message and I entered 'Hello' and hit 'enter'

```
Bot loaded. Type a message and press enter (use '/stop' to exit):
hello
```

Following is the **'Attribute error'** message I got:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\
label.py:151: DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous
. Returning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use `array.size >
 0` to check that an array is not empty.
  if diff:
Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\threading.py", line 916, in
_bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\threading.py", line 864, in
run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\chan
nels\console.py", line 110, in record_messages
    for response in bot_responses:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\chan
nels\console.py", line 67, in send_message_receive_stream
    stream=True) as r:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

This was the **'Connection Aborted Error'**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.
    py", line 936, in handle_one_response
        self.run_application()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.
    py", line 910, in run_application
        self.process_result()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.
    py", line 896, in process_result
        self.write(data)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.
    py", line 742, in write
        self._write_with_headers(data)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.
    py", line 764, in _write_with_headers
        self._write(data)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.
    py", line 724, in _write
        self._sendall(data)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.
    py", line 702, in _sendall
        self.socket.sendall(data)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socket
    3.py", line 418, in sendall
        data_sent += self.send(data_memory[data_sent:], flags)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\sschatbot\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socket
    3.py", line 391, in send
        return _socket.socket.send(self._sock, data, flags)
    ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted b
    y the software in your host machine
    Thu Dec  6 16:25:33 2018 {'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REMOTE_PORT': '50028', 'H
    TTP_HOST': 'localhost:5005', (hidden keys: 23)} failed with ConnectionAbortedErr
    or

    127.0.0.1 - - [2018-12-06 16:25:33] "POST /webhooks/rest/webhook?stream=true&tok
    en= HTTP/1.1" 200 153 0.265938
```

Comment: It works after restarting the custom action server by running:

`python -m rasa_core_sdk.endpoint --actions actions`

Then ran the model using:

`python dialogue_management_model.py`